# UISwitch sometime don't call value changed

Tags: ios, ios8, uiswitch

https://github.com/john-07/switcher/tree/master

When UISwitch is switched several times, its On/Off label status does not concur with status of UISwitch graphical element.

Error occures when UISwitch and UITableView are placed on the same screen. If UITableView is not present on the screen, no error occures. The application is run on device without a cord.
image
[image]
video
http://youtu.be/FtQqv7xreRU

```
-(void)doSwitch:(BOOL)val{
    title.text = val? @"On" : @"Off";
} 

- (IBAction)onValueChanged:(UISwitch*)sender {
    BOOL on = sender.on;
    [self doSwitch:on];
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: Why are you used dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ?
I think issue comes it, because async calls interrupt the correct sequence of functions calls.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether i'm using dispatch_async or not. Wll remove it from code.